# How to make ASMR sounds?

Tags: processing, binaural

Do you really need binaural microphones, e.g.

or can you just post-process somehow using EQ and reverb? What steps are needed to create a spooky whisper effect from a regular recorded whisper?

Now I know there are other questions that ask about using binaural mics and stereo setups. But I want to not buy any more equipment. Is there a way to get an approximate ASMR spatial effect with just software?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a cheap way out you could just plug some ear-bud headphones into your mic-inputs. Headphones can work in reverse too! then place the earbuds in your ears but facing outwards and you'll get a bin-aural recording. This will work better with actual mics placed on either side of your head.

You can simulate the binaural experience using reverbs and eq but the easiest way is to use your pan option so you can move the localisation of the sound simple. In programs like Logic or most DAWs you simply have a small circular module where you move a dot around in a circle.

Experiment with different techniques and you can have a lot of fun.